# Texdoc doesn't return the expected document

Tags: texdoc, linuxfedora

I have a Fedora 36 system with `texlive-scheme-full` installed. I type `texdoc pgf` in the command line, but the returned documentation is for `pgf-cmykshadings` package. I also typed `texdoc -s pgf` and I got the following:

```
1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-cmykshadings/pgf-cmykshadings.pdf
 2 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/pgf-pie-manual.pdf
 3 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/description.html
 4 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/RELEASE_NOTES.md
 5 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-cmykshadings/README.md
 6 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/README.md
 7 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/LICENSE-GPL2.txt
 8 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/LICENSE-LPPL1.3c.txt
 9 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-pie/COPYING
10 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfmorepages/pgfmorepages.pdf
11 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfornament-han/pgfornament-han_manual.pdf
12 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bbox/pgfmanual4bbox.pdf
13 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfornament-han/lppl-1-3c.txt
14 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfornament-han/README.md
15 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfmorepages/README
16 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfornament-han/heavenlyclouds-sample.pdf
17 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfornament-han/xiaoshan-sample.pdf
```

Any ideas why texdoc doesn't return the expected [pgfmanual](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)?

Comment: The texlive versions packaged for linux are often out of date. Consider installing a vanilla texlive from tug.org. For example `pgf-cmykshadings ` has been moved to obsolete and is no longer in texlive https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-cmykshadings

Comment: It seems fishy that you only get hits from /doc/latex and nothing at all from /doc/generic ...

Comment: I installed it with `sudo dnf texlive-scheme-full`.

Comment: at first check if you actually have the pgfmanual (it should be in doc/generic/pgf).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked, and it is not there.

Comment: well then it is not so surprising that texdoc can't find it.

Comment: There is a subpackage `texlive-pgf-doc` for Fedora 36, not sure why that is not included in texlive-scheme-full but I guess if you install the subpackage separately then you get pgfmanual.pdf as well.

Comment: @Marijn Maybe the doc's are not included due to minimalism of Fedora? But I would expect the "main" manuals to be included only (in such case).